# onmouseover class 1 onmouseout class 2 Strange border.

Tags: css, onmouseover

I'm trying to make a link image.

everything works with link but when I add a 2nd image to show when hover - then a strange border shows around it. Any ideas how to avoid the border? 
I cant add a pics here so look here:

http://postimg.org/image/7q0jkc99t/

in html:

```
<div id="Oobj14">
<a href="formularz.html"><img id="Ggeo9" class="przed" onmouseover="this.className='po'" 

onmouseout="this.className='przed'" alt=""></div>
```

in css:

```
.przed{
background: url('image/dolacz.png') no-repeat;
width: 249px;
height: 70px;
border-style: none;
}

.po{
background: url('image/dolacz2.png') no-repeat;
width: 249px;
height: 70px;
border-style: none;
}
```

and for the image:

```
#Oobj14 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10px;
  z-index: 13;
  left: 43.20em;
  top: 40.70em;
  width: 143px;
  height: 56px;
  border-style: none;
}

img#Ggeo9 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity:1.0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use javascript at all?  I'd throw away the images and simply use backgrounds.  Use CSS :hover to switch to another background

HTML:

```
<div id="Oobj14">
<a href="formularz.html">Descriptive text</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Oobj14 a {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10px;
  z-index: 13;
  left: 43.20em;
  top: 40.70em;
  width: 143px;
  height: 56px;
  border-style: none;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-indent:-2000px;
}

#Oobj14 a {
  background: url('image/dolacz.png') no-repeat;
  width: 249px;
  height: 70px;
  border-style: none;
}

#Oobj14 a:hover {
  background: url('image/dolacz2.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: although -any idea now how to make the 2nd background load with page load? to not wait untill hover ...

Comment: Glad I could help.  See here how you can preload: http://perishablepress.com/a-way-to-preload-images-without-javascript-that-is-so-much-better/